# Export MySQL to .txt tab with column headers all in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL on Linux (CentOS). I want need to be able to export a MySQL table to create a .txt tab separated file with the headers for so it can be import into Salesforce.

This works for a .txt tab separated file:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable INTO OUTFILE 'data.txt'
```

But it doesn't include the column headers. I prefer not to use the command line or a PHP program to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SELECT 'ColName1', 'ColName2', 'ColName3'
UNION ALL
SELECT ColName1, ColName2, ColName3
INTO OUTFILE 'data.txt'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM myTable;
```